# Streaming pdf file from node server randomly just shows binary data on browser

Tags: node.js, pdf, express, sails.js

I have a node app (specifically sails app) that is serving pdf file. My code for serving file looks like this.

```
request.get(pdfUrl).pipe(res)
```

And when I view the url for pdf, it renders the pdf fine. But sometimes, it just renders the binary data of pdf on browser like given below.

```
%PDF-1.4 1 0 obj << /Title (��) /Creator (��wkhtmltopdf
```

I am not able to figure out why is it failing to serve the pdf correctly just randomly. Is it chrome thing? or Am I missing something?

Comment: With the answer below did you notice any change in the headers in the browser console? For the request what are the exact request headers and what are the exact response headers (please post them here).

Comment: @kxhitiz you are using request module for getting the pdf from its url, right.

Comment: @Nivesh Yes I am using request module.

Comment: So you need to confirm if it is the rendering that is failing, or if it is pdf itself that is invalid. Can you open it using a native pdf browser after downloading like : `curl -o my_pdf.pdf http://my_pdf_link`? (from your server)

Answer (score 2):

Leaving this here in the hope that it helps somebody - I have had similar issues multiple times and its either of two things:

1. You're using an HTTP connection to an HTTPS delivery (this is typical with websockets, where you must specify `:443` in addition to the `wss`.
2. `request`'s encoding parameter is serving plaintext instead of objects. This is done by setting `encoding` to null as follows: `request({url: myUrl, encoding: null})`.
3. Content types in headers - steering clear of this since it's obvious/others have covered this substantially enough already :)

I am pretty sure you're facing this due to (2). Have a look at https://github.com/request/request

> encoding - Encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. If
>   null, the body is returned as a Buffer. Anything else (including the
>   default value of undefined) will be passed as the encoding parameter
>   to toString() (meaning this is effectively utf8 by default). (Note: if
>   you expect binary data, you should set encoding: null.)

---

Since, the aforementioned suggestions didn't work for you, would like to see forensics from the following:

- Are files that fail over a particular size? Is this a buffer issue at some level?
- Does the presence of a certain character in the file cause this because it breaks some of your script?
- Are the meta-data sections and file-endings the same across a failed and a successful file? How any media file is signed up-top, and how it's truncated down-bottom, can greatly impact how it is interpreted

Comment: Yeah, I have verified the stuffs you mentioned. But it still displays  binary pdf randomly. I compared the response header information when it displays correctly and the ones when it displays binary data, and turn out both are same.

Comment: @kxhitiz What is your analysis as regards file-size - are the files that fail over a certain size? It shouldn't be the case, but best to eliminate the probability of running out of an expected buffer

Answer (score 1):

You may need to include the content type header `application/pdf` in the node response to tell the recipient that what they're receiving is a PDF. Some browsers are smart enough to determine the content type from the data stream, but you can't assume that's always the case.

Comment: Did that, still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

When Chrome downloads the PDF as text I would check the very end of the file. The PDF file contains the obligatory `xref` table at the end. So **every** valid PDF file should end with the following sequence: `%EOF`. If not then the request was interrupted or something gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You also need HTTP header:

```
Content-Disposition:inline; filename=sample.pdf;
```

And

```
Content-Length: 200
```

Did you try to save what ever binary stuff you get on disk and open it manually by PDF reader? It could be corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying both of these:

`Content-Type: application/pdf`
`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"`

(or controlling Mime Type in other ways: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types)